# Unable to access global parameters within KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have an `Apache Flink` job that initially stores certain configuration data as "global job parameters":

```java
final var env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
final var executionConfig = env.getConfig();
...
executionConfig.setGlobalJobParameters(params);
```

The problem I'm facing is that I have a custom `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema` where I need access to those — in the same way any rich user function could do.

I have several fields/members that are getting initialized within there because that class is doing a little bit more than just deserializing messages, so I need them.

Is there a way to do something similar to `getRuntimeContext().getExecutionConfig().getGlobalJobParameters()` within any of the deserializers or would it be better to split the flow and do several operations within more "specialized" function(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DeserializationSchema.InitializationContext` that's passed in doesn't provide access to the execution configuration. But what you can do is to define a constructor for your custom `KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema` to which you pass the configuration.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work. Another issue is that the application is using Spring Boot as well (for no reason), so I have a combination of Spring Beans and usual _up'ed_ classes, and Flink doesn't play well with these. On the other hand, wouldn't that `open` method do the same as the constructor, and vice-versa?

Comment: Not exactly. The constructor is called when the main() method is executed in the client, and the resulting object is serialized and sent into the cluster. After deserialization in the cluster, the open method is called on an instance in each task manager.